# Background image captures in half after using DomToImage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, screenshot

So I'm trying out Dom-to-Image but ran into a deadend. I have this div with a fixed `width` and `height` of `700px` and `500`px respectively. This is the div which I want to take a screenshot of with `Dom-to-Image` plugin.

When the `div` is `left-aligned` on the viewport, the screen capture is perfect and I can download the image. But if I make the div center with `margin: 0 auto;`, then I get one-third of the screenshot and not the full image.

Here's the issue when it is centered:

[image]

What I want:

No matter where my div is placed, I only want to take the screenshot of that full div. How can I do that?

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    const imgDiv                    = document.querySelector('#div');
    const downloadBtn               = document.querySelector('#download');


   $(downloadBtn).click(() => {
          domtoimage.toBlob(imgDiv).then( blob => {
                saveAs(blob, 'myImage.png');
          });
   });
   
   
});
```

```css
#div {
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url('https://img.glyphs.co/img?q=85&w=900&src=aHR0cHM6Ly9zMy5tZWRpYWxvb3QuY29tL3Jlc291cmNlcy9HZW9tZXRyaWMtQmFja2dyb3VuZC1QYXR0ZXJucy1QcmV2aWV3LTJiLmpwZw==');
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.text-block {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.text,
.name {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

.text {
    padding: 0 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.name {
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.0/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="div">
     <div class="text-block">
          <p class="text">Booooooooooooooossss </p>
          <p class="name">s</p>
     </div>
</div>

<button id="download">Download</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the docs:

> This library uses a feature of SVG that allows having arbitrary HTML content inside of the `<foreignObject>` tag.

So it basically copies the element with the css applied to it and runs them again within the `<foreignObject>`.

I assume this is done as such in case there's a background or some kind of coloration applied to the element, They probably didn't think much about the css properties that would alter placement or I just didn't read everything in the documentation.

With that said, To avoid this You will have to nest your element.

All your css property that alter the position of the element should be put on the container, everything else can stay on the DOM element you want to convert to an image.

```js
var NodeToImage = document.querySelector('[NodeToImage]');


domtoimage.toPng(NodeToImage)
  .then(function(dataUrl) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
  });
```

```css
/* Container to nest the DOM element */
/* margin is applied to it instead*/
[ctr] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}


/* This is the DOM element to be converted */
[NodeToImage] {
  background: orange;
  height: 100%;
  /* To match the height */
}

img {
  border: 1px solid;/* For the preview*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js" integrity="sha512-01CJ9/g7e8cUmY0DFTMcUw/ikS799FHiOA0eyHsUWfOetgbx/t6oV4otQ5zXKQyIrQGTHSmRVPIgrgLcZi/WMA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div ctr>
  <div NodeToImage></div>
</div>
```

---

**Side Note: I tried to look through the issues on Github, and couldn't find anything related to this, maybe i missed it. You might want to make one**

Comment: Hey mate. Sorry for posting the issue without any code. I kind of forgot. It has been added now. Can you please take a look at it? I have applied ```margin``` to the container div which is what is making the image cut in half.

Comment: @Zak You're trying to print `#div` which is a container for a bunch of elements, you have to nest that element it self, and move all placement altering css properties to it. Don't forget about the height and width so they would match because now we using a different element. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Tater101/to18eqfg/2/)

Comment: Oh now I understand what you said. I wrapped it with another div and gave it a fixed height and width and also margin to make it center. Now it captures the full image.